# dynamically populate table in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

So I'm reading data out of a database and want to display it on a webpage like this:

```
Name  Age   Fav#  ...other info

Bob   11    15 

Joe   13    4
```

I want to make a website that updates the contents of its table based on the database. I know the number of columns that the database has but not necessarily the number of rows.

I was thinking just writing the .aspx file and generating the HTML and values when the database is read, but I was looking at some similar stackoverflow questions and they advise against it? The suggestion was to create a template .aspx file and just populate it, but how would you do that if you don't know the exact number of rows to make?

Also if I programatically write my own Something.aspx files and create a Something.aspx.cs file, will they automatically link together?

I'm new to ASP.net and C#, so I'm not sure if there's an easier way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using ASP.NET I'd suggest using [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/2s019wc0.aspx) control to display table data. It has a lot more possibilities (like built in paging and sorting). And you do not need to know in advance number of rows - GridView will render whatever is thrown at it, turning on paging if nessesery